# Does Xcode 4.3 support distcc?

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4.2 had a tab in preferences that dealt with sharing compilation tasks within your local network.  It used bonjour and distcc to farm out compilation to other macs on the same network that had the option selected.  I no longer see this after upgrading to Xcode 4.3.  Is it gone?  Is there any way to get it back, apart from downgrading?

Comment: It looks like it's gone.  Several people have asked the same question on the Apple Developer Forums but nobody has answered them.  The silence is deafening...

Comment: And the silence goes on... Pretty amazing how they removed such feature just like that.

Comment: It was documented as deprecated in 4.2 and slated to be removed in 4.3 in the release notes: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/xcode_42_for_lion_readme.pdf (I overlooked it then, also)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, distcc was removed in Xcode 4.3. If you'd like to continue using it, you'll have to stick with Xcode 4.2.

Comment: just as well, 4.3 broke cmake too

Answer (score 1):

Although Xcode 4.3 removed support for `distcc` and the settings to enable or disable distributed builds; the `distccd` processes are still running because they forget to delete the launchdaemon plist.

But you can simply delete it manually with:

```
sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.distccd.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

After some web-research, I have a guess at the reason for removing distcc from XCode:

With clang, the compilation time was actually improved so far, that preprocessing typically takes longer than the actual compilation. distcc does not yet support precompiled headers, so to use distcc, you actually have to preprocess each file individually on the machine where distcc is invoked. So preprocessing becomes the bottleneck and distcc is actually slower than using local clang with preprocessed headers.

Beware, that this is just a guess based on bits and pieces of information that I could find on the web...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they removed support for distributed builds in 4.3. However, this was not documented in the release notes.